# Amazon s3 Upload error Path "c:\fakepath"

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, amazon-s3, html5-audio

I am trying to create an upload feature for a site of mine and I am uploading the file to Amazon S3. The issue is weird...  I can upload a small file size successfully 100% of the time but I have found that a file of 11mb or more doesn't seem to work.  What happens is the larger files path on the db ends up having "c:\fakepath\" in it.  The smaller files do not have that.  Does anyone have any experience with this issue?  It seems weird that I don't consistently get that error, only on the larger files?  Does Amazon have a file size limit or an upload timeout limit?  Help please.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, Amazon S3 have file size limit. You can upload file in as single entity max size of 5GB and using Multipart api you can upload file max size of 5TB.

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: It's not that I'm getting an error... The file upload process seems to complete and then when I check the path on the audio player it has a C:\fakepath in the file path and also it doesn't show up on the amazon server

Comment: at amazon you will get the file as you supply key in putObject method. Check are you sending objectkey like "c:\fakepath" or simple objectname